# Find size of 1D array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2010

A sub calls a function that in turn doest stuff and returns an array. The probem is I need to know the size of that array in my sub. is there a quick line to find the size of that array? I know i can do it with a littel for  loop bt this seems unecessary.
This is how it goes:

```
Sub innout(lastupdate As Long, lrcr As Long)

Dim numclosed As Long, numnew As Long
Dim lblvar As Variant
Dim tblcr As Range
Dim finishdates As Range
Dim msg As Long
Dim resp As String, ops() As Long, cps() As Long
Dim i As Long

    listallsupv

'do stuff...
end sub



Function listallsupv() As String()

Dim las() As String

Dim lrs As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
Dim supervsheet As Worksheet

Set supervsheet = Sheets("Superviseurs")

lrs = supervsheet.Range("A1").Offset(supervsheet.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim las(1 To lrs) As String

i = 1

For r = 2 To lrs
    For j = 1 To i
        If supervsheet.Range("B" & r).Value = las(j) Then
            GoTo nextj
    End If
    Next
    las(i) = supervsheet.Range("B" & r).Value
    i = i + 1
nextj:
Next

ReDim Preserve las(1 To i)

End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: By "size" you probably mean length? As in, number of items. Try `UBound(las)`.

Comment: And `LBound(..)`, you need both to be sure.

Comment: las() does not exist in the sub. i need to do it in the sub. so i would so lets say i=ubound(listallsuperv)?

Comment: lowerbound is always 1. but what is the syntak of the Ubound line?

Comment: @user2385809: I would define `las` as being a global variable - define it outside all the functions so it is available to all. Otherwise you need to pass it as an argument to `listallsupv`.

Comment: `size = (ubound(arr)-lbound(arr))+1`  And you need to return the array from your function `listallsupv = las`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah I found it. I just made the array in my original sub and called another sub to populate it by reference adnn also return the length. Ya thanks Tim I hadn't even noticed that at first.

```
Sub innout(lastupdate As Long, lrcr As Long)

Dim i As Long
Dim las() As String

Call populate_las(las(), i)

'bla bla

End Sub


Sub populate_las(ByRef las() As String, ByRef i As Long)

Dim lrs As Long
Dim j As Long, r As Long
Dim supervsheet As Worksheet

Set supervsheet = Sheets("Superviseurs")

lrs = supervsheet.Range("A1").Offset(supervsheet.Rows.count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim las(1 To lrs) As String

i = 1

For r = 2 To lrs
    For j = 1 To i
        If supervsheet.Range("B" & r).Value = las(j) Then
            GoTo nextj
    End If
    Next
    las(i) = supervsheet.Range("B" & r).Value
    i = i + 1
nextj:
Next

ReDim Preserve las(1 To (i - 1))

End Sub
```

Thanks again!